# Python C API - How to inherit from your own python class?

Tags: python-c-api

The [newtypes tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html) shows you how to inherit from a base python class. Can you inherit from your own python class? Something like this?

```
  PyObject *mod = PyImport_AddModule("foomod");
  PyObject *o = PyObject_GetAttrString(mod, "BaseClass");
  PyTypeObject *t = o->ob_type;
  FooType.tp_base = t;
  if (PyType_Ready(&FooType  ) < 0) return NULL;
```

though you need to define your struct with the base class as the first member per the documentation so it sounds like this is not possible? ie how would I setup the Foo struct?

```
typedef struct {
    PyListObject list;
    int state;
} SubListObject;
```

What I'm really trying to do is subclass [_UnixSelectorEventLoop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9fdc64cf1266b6d5bf0503847b5c38e5edc53a14/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py) and it seems like my only solution is to define a python class that derives from my C class and from _UnixSelectorEventLoop with my C class listed first so that it can override methods in the other base class.

Comment: I've updated the link to the documentation, rather than the github source that generates the documentation, because some code snippets are included from other files on the github source so it's quite hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I think you're basically right on your assessment:

> it seems like my only solution is to define a python class that derives from my C class and from `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` with my C class listed first so that it can override methods in the other base class.

You can't define a class that inherits from a Python class because it'd need to start with a C `struct` of basically arbitrary size.

There's a couple of other options that you might like to consider:

1. You could create a class the manual way by calling `PyType_Type`. See [this useful answer on a question about multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522999/4657412) which is another sort of inheritance that the C API struggles with. This *probably* limits you too much, since you can't have C attributes, but you can have C functions.
2. You could do "inheritance by composition" - i.e. have you `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` as part of the object, then forward `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to it in the event of unknown attributes. It's probably easier to see what I mean with Python code (which is simply but tediously transformed into C API code)

   ```
   class YourClass:
       def __init__(self,...):
           self.state = 0
           self._usel = _UnixSelectorEventLoop()
       def __getattr__(self, name):
           return getattr(self._usel, 'name')
       def __setattr__(self, name, value):
           if name in self.__dict__:
               object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
           else:
               setattr(self._usel, name, value)
       # maybe __hasattr__ and __delattr__ too?
   ```

   I'm hoping to avoid having to write this C API code myself, but the slots are [`tp_getattro`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) and [`tp_setattro`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_setattro). Note that `__getattr__` will need to be more comprehensive in the C version, since it acts closer to the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) in Python. The flipside is that `isinstance` and `issubclass` will fail, which may or may not be an issue for you.